# Using Power Automate, how can I change the subject of an email before I save it to a SharePoint folder?

Tags: sharepoint, outlook, power-automate

Here is what I want to accomplish: When an email is sent to my inbox, I want to save it down a SharePoint folder (as a .eml) with the Subject as the file name.

The issue I'm having: Special characters in the Subject line (e.g. ":", "/", etc.) are causing the flow to fail.

Here's my flow currently (which works as expected when the subject contains no special characters):
[image: flow that saves email to sharepoint]

My initial idea was to click on Subject in the Create file step, and then click on dynamic content to use the replace function to change the Subject string, but I'm not sure how to reference the Subject string in a formula (or even if this is the correct approach):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint has some restrictions on the file name.
[image]
You could get the information here:https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/invalid-file-names-and-file-types-in-onedrive-and-sharepoint-64883a5d-228e-48f5-b3d2-eb39e07630fa?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us#invalidfilefoldernames

When I test the Create File action, it automatically replaces the characters in the subject with '_'.
[image]
[image]

[How to use replace function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#replace)
So far, the use of regular expressions in the replace function is not supported